# Connect Azure SQL Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to use a Azure SQL instance and use code first migrations to create the database.

When I use without run migrations it throws an error:

> Invalid object name 'MyObject'

And I can see in the exception details my connectionID, because of this I believe that it could handle the connection.

But when I try to use migrations database update to create the object, I can't connect when I use `myContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` I can't see the connection id and the exception is

> can't connect to the server

I already created a firewall rule to my ip address and it didn't worked.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.

The string connection was wrong, i copied from the VS SqlExplorer, i thought it was correct but that wasn't the true.

I see on the manager azure old portal examples for string connection using tcp indicating the port.